# GAE Java URL Fetch; get the status message using low-level API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, httpurlconnection, urlfetch

I am writing a Java GAE app and relying on URL Fetch to send HTTP requests to other servers (see [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/). Up until this point, I had been using their `HttpUrlConnection` interface implementation in order to use the URL Fetch service. However, I am rewriting my app to use the **low-level API** instead of `HttpUrlConnection` because I want to send *asynchronous* HTTP requests.

**My question:** What is the URL Fetch low level API equivalent of [HttpUrlConnection.getResponseMessage():String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseMessage%28%29)? Based on what I see from the [low-level API javadoc for HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/HTTPResponse), I am not sure of what method I should use. I can get the response code alright, but I'd like to read a useful message along with the code, especially for when an error occurs.

Thanks.